# php cannot interpret escape character for exporting function

Tags: php, string

my php server cannot interpret "\n" as (LF or CR). something wrong with my php.ini?

here an example code:

```
<?php echo "hell o boys \n hell o girls \t hell o gays"; ?>
```

it's just print:

```
hell o boys hell o girls hell o gays
```

where i expect to be

```
hell o boys 
 hell o girls      hell o gays
```

needed help please. really bothered with small things like this. 
I don't want to use regex.

in this case, i want to use this function below, but it won't work because of the escape char prolem.
here:

```
<?php
function export_excel_csv()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("database",$conn);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $rec = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($rec);

    for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name($rec,$i)."\\t";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rec))
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach($row as $value)
        {                                            
            if((!isset($value)) || ($value == ""))
            {
                $value = "\\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\\n";
    }

    $data = str_replace("\\r" , "" , $data);

    if ($data == "")
    {
        $data = "\\n No Record Found!\n";                        
    }

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\\n$data";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use `<br>` for new line..

Comment: Browsers don't see `\n` as a new line, just as white space; you need to use an html `<br />` tag. Use `\n` (or the built-in PHP_EOL constant) if you're writing to a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
nl2br
```

function to replace with line break for \n. Like this

```
$str = "hell o boys \n hell o girls \t hell o gays";

echo nl2br($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "hell o boys \n hell o girls \t hell o gays";    
$a=str_replace('\n',PHP_EOL,$a);
echo $a;
```

if u want to display code in html .
try

```
echo "<pre>{$a}</pre>";
```